# Como puedo cargar el spinner luego de que terminen todos los get reponse del androidnetworking?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

Lo que sucede es que estoy usando la libreria de FastAndroidNetworking y cuando realizo un get para cargar la base de datos local(estoy usando ROOM), esta termina despues de que cargo el spinner (estoy usando el MaterialSpinner), de que manera le puedo decir al spinner que espere hasta que se termine de cargar la base. 
Aqui esta el codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es mejor que en cambio de las fotos copies y pegues el codigo y los metodos

Answer (score 0):

En el metodo `cargarTodosEquipos()` el `onResponse` te esta diciendo que ya termino , entonces antes de tu toast `"EQUIPOS CARGADOS SATISFACTORIAMENTE"` , setea ahi que cargue el spinner

Entonces, saca esta linea del `onCreate();`

```
spinner.setItems(db.equipoDao().equipos());
```

y la pones arriba de ese Toast en el onResponse

```
spinner.setItems(db.equipoDao().equipos());
```

Lo que pasa es que el onCreate() al ejecutarse, te ejecuta todo de una sola pasada , y mientras la base dde datos se va cargando ya te ejecuto el codigo del spinner para que llene con datos cuando no tiene, entonces moviendo el seteo del spinner a cuando termina la base de datos de cargar los datos es lo que te deberia cargar todos los datos una vez terminado.